# Python for loop for Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to take mean of a window (5x5).
And this window beginning will move +1 at x axis. After first x axis finished, window will move +1 at y axis and will start a new loop. And I have to say that bant4.tif is an image 512x512.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


nir = mpimg.imread('bant4.tif')

A = np.array(nir)

for k in range(0,508):
    for j in range(0,508):
        ilk = A[k][j] + A[k][j+1] + A[k][j+2] + A[k][j+3] + A[k][j+4]
        ikinci = A[k+1][j] + A[k+1][j+1] + A[k+1][j+2] + A[k+1][j+3] + A[k+1][j+4]
        ucuncu = A[k+2][j] + A[k+2][j+1] + A[k+2][j+2] + A[k+2][j+3] + A[k+2][j+4]
        dorduncu = A[k+3][j] + A[k+3][j+1] + A[k+3][j+2] + A[k+3][j+3] + A[k+3][j+4]
        besinci = A[k+4][j] + A[k+4][j+1] + A[k+4][j+2] + A[k+4][j+3] + A[k+4][j+4]

        ort = (ilk + ikinci + ucuncu + dorduncu + besinci) / 5 
        ort.tofile('ort.txt')
```

Here is the error.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 19
ort = (ilk + ikinci + ucuncu + dorduncu + besinci) / 5
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 17
besinci = A[k+4][j] + A[k+4][j+1] + A[k+4][j+2] + A[k+4][j+3] + A[k+4][j+4]
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 14
ikinci = A[k+1][j] + A[k+1][j+1] + A[k+1][j+2] + A[k+1][j+3] + A[k+1][j+4]
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 15
ucuncu = A[k+2][j] + A[k+2][j+1] + A[k+2][j+2] + A[k+2][j+3] + A[k+2][j+4]
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 13
ilk = A[k][j] + A[k][j+1] + A[k][j+2] + A[k][j+3] + A[k][j+4]
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Celik\Desktop\ödev5.py", line 16
dorduncu = A[k+3][j] + A[k+3][j+1] + A[k+3][j+2] + A[k+3][j+3] + A[k+3][j+4]
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
```

Comment: are you sure that size of your image is 512x512?  can you check that? Besides, even in that case you get overflow when j or k is large enough, because e.g. j+1 or k+1 would overflow if j=511 or j=511.

Comment: It is 512*512. @Ashalynd

Comment: in this case, you get overflow for the reasons mentioned above: e.g. as soon as k=509, A[k+3][j]  (used when you calculate dorduncu) overflows.

Comment: Thank you @Ashalynd. I understood it. But now I have another overflow.. I will change codes and error.

Comment: Simplest way to bounds check this would be more or less to check if you'd be able to meet the last condition of each of the lines, prior to starting, or at the beginning of theloop checking if you couldsatisy themax bound for each line ie. for .... /n if j +max inct|| k+ max inc > break

Comment: Thank you @L.P. Solved the bounds error. .But now There is another error.